# nmcli dev shows weird '\024\353\266G\005\271 wifi unavailable -- '

Tags: linux, wifi, nmcli

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to install 'TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter'
After following the procedure [here](https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210629), cannot connect to wifi and nmcli dev shows weird '\024\353\266G\005\271  wifi      unavailable  --    '.

Why wlan0 does not appear and instead '\024\353\266G\005\271' appears?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The weird text is a fairly standard way of rendering text that does not correspond to readable ASCII. Each triplet after the `\` is a 3-digit octal value. It looks like your adapter has picked up a UTF-8 (or random) name during installation.

Comment: I see. But i cannot connect the device by 
owner@Alexander:~$ ip link set \024\353\266G\005\271 up
Cannot find device "024353266G005271"